# transpose columns and create list in new column

Tags: python, pandas

Very difficult question to fit into a title. Let me explain:

let's say i have a df like this:

```
id          'state': 'texas'    'phone_type': 'iphone'  'email_domain': 'gmail'
111         1                   0                       1
222         0                   1                       1
123         0                   1                       0
234         1                   0                       0
432         0                   0                       1
```

#code for df

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id'
                                ,"'state': 'texas'"
                                ,"'phone_type': 'iphone'"
                                ,"'email_domain': 'gmail'"
                               ]
                       ,data=[
                           [111,1,0,1]
                           ,[222,0,1,1]
                           ,[123,0,1,0]
                           ,[234,1,0,0]
                           ,[432,0,0,1]
                       ])
```

how can i take the columns, transpose them to rows in a new df, and put the ids that = 1 in a list in a new column? and throw in one more column of the count of ids. Like this:

```
attr                        ids_list        count_ids
'state': 'texas'            [111,234]       2
'phone_type': 'iphone'      [222,123]       2
'email_domain': 'gmail'     [111,222,432]   3
```

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Comment: It seems like you've transformed some pre-existing data using a one-hot encoding to get your current dataframe.  You should probably just transform _that_ original dataframe instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd


new_df = defaultdict(list)
for c in df_test.columns[1:]:
    ids = df_test['id'][(df_test[c].values).astype(bool)]
    new_df['attr'].append(c)
    new_df['ids_list'].append(ids.values.tolist())
    new_df['count_ids'].append(len(ids))

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df)
```

Note that this assumes "id" is the first column in your original dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

In *pandas* way (with [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)):

```
res = pd.melt(df_test, id_vars=['id'], var_name='attr')\
    .pipe(lambda df: df[df['value'].eq(1)])\
    .groupby('attr')['id'].agg([list, 'size'])\
    .rename(columns={'list': 'ids', 'size': 'count'}).reset_index()
print(res)
```

---

```
                      attr             ids  count
0  'email_domain': 'gmail'  [111, 222, 432]     3
1   'phone_type': 'iphone'       [222, 123]     2
2         'state': 'texas'       [111, 234]     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your questions sounds like it would be much easier to use a (default)dict to contain the data instead of a DataFrame. If you, however, wich to do it in pandas, you could use this:

```py
results_df = pd.DataFrame()
results_df['attr'] = [
    "'state': 'texas'",
    "'phone_type': 'iphone'",
    "'email_domain': 'gmail'",
]
results_df['ids_list'] = [df_test[df_test[col] == 1]['id'].tolist()
                          for col in results_df['attr']]
results_df['count_ids'] = results_df['ids_list'].apply(len)
```

`print(results_df)`

```py
                      attr         ids_list  count_ids
0         'state': 'texas'       [111, 234]          2
1   'phone_type': 'iphone'       [222, 123]          2
2  'email_domain': 'gmail'  [111, 222, 432]          3
```